# Do any world leaders have their image featured on vaccination certificates?

Tags: covid-19, public-health, vaccine, public-image

Prime minister Modi of India's image is [featured on most (if not all) vaccination certificates](https://www.indiatoday.in/india/story/west-bengal-covid-certificate-mamata-banerjee-pm-modi-1811234-2021-06-05).

Do any other world leaders print their own image on such certificates?  Failing that, do other leaders engage in other forms of self-promotion on Covid relief measures?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127254/discussion-on-question-by-gary-2-do-any-world-leaders-have-their-image-featured). Please use the comments to discuss improvements / whether or not it's on-topic only. Use the chatroom if you want to discuss.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, in fact, Trump engaged in just that: [In unprecedented move, Treasury orders Trump’s name printed on stimulus checks](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/coming-to-your-1200-relief-check-donald-j-trumps-name/2020/04/14/071016c2-7e82-11ea-8013-1b6da0e4a2b7_story.html).

> The Treasury Department has ordered President Trump’s name printed on stimulus checks the Internal Revenue Service is rushing to send to tens of millions of Americans, a process that could slow their delivery by a few days, senior IRS officials said.
>
> The unprecedented decision, finalized late Monday, means that when recipients open the $1,200 paper checks the IRS is scheduled to begin sending to 70 million Americans in coming days, “President Donald J. Trump” will appear on the left side of the payment.
>
> It will be the first time a president’s name appears on an IRS disbursement, whether a routine refund or one of the handful of checks the government has issued to taxpayers in recent decades either to stimulate a down economy or share the dividends of a strong one.

If, as a Canadian citizen, my Federal or provincial prime minister put their name, *or that of their party*, to the *[deliverables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deliverable)* `*` of any Covid relief activities, I would have been extremely annoyed.  And that's irrespective of whether I supported that party or not.

**The relief is being provided by the government (and paid for by taxpayers).  IF mentioned, that is, in itself, is sufficient implicit endorsement of the leader/party in charge.  Self-promotion or party promotion, should have been disallowed as enlisting public resources for campaigning purposes.**

`*` claiming credit for a policy or action in political speech is normal and expected.  In the case of Covid, there is so much downside associated with being in charge during this crisis that it would be unreasonable to muzzle highlighting one's good deeds in communications.  That is very different from self-promoting on the actual cheques or vaccines.

Comment: Don't forget he also sent letters to all the people who got the money to make sure they knew. https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/his-name-on-stimulus-checks-trump-sends-a-gushing-letter-to-90-million-people/2020/04/28/04143a62-8999-11ea-ac8a-fe9b8088e101_story.html